# Angled text in latex table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to recreate this table from excel (it's in danish):

[image: Excel danish table]

But I cant get the angle of the text correct in latex:
[image]

I'm using this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry} %margin
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[danish]{cleveref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage[tablename=Table]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\hspace{-40px}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.1\linewidth}|p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.15\linewidth}|p{0.15\linewidth}|}         \hline 
        Titel & \rotatebox[origin=b]{45}{\parbox{25mm}{C-bøjle m. hydrauliske   stempler}}  & \rotatebox[origin=b]{45}{\parbox{25mm}{Stor møtrik med gearet slagnøgle}} & {\color[HTML]{FF0000} \rotatebox[origin=b]{45}{\parbox{25mm}{Foldekrog på excentrisk aksel}}} & {\color[HTML]{FF0000} \rotatebox[origin=b]{45}{\parbox{25mm}{Hydraulisk drejecylinder}}} & {\color[HTML]{FF0000} \rotatebox[origin=b]{45}{\parbox{25mm}{Fremskudt ærme med indgribende hydrauliske stifter}}} & {\color[HTML]{FF0000} \rotatebox[origin=b]{45}{\parbox{25mm}{Stor møtrik med hydraulik cylinder}}} & {\color[HTML]{FF0000} \rotatebox[origin=b]{45}{\parbox{25mm}{Multi-møtrik m. bæltedrev}}}\\
        \hline 
        Konus & x & 1b & x & x & x & x & x \\
        \hline 
        Chamfer & 2a & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
        \hline 
        Stifter (fast) & 3a & 3b & x & x & x & x & x \\
        \hline 
        Stifter (fremskrubbelig) & 4a & x & x & x & x & x & x\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Kombinationer af udarbejdet klemme- og centreringsløsninger}
    \label{tab:kombinationer}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'll change it ASAP

Comment: Welcome. // Thank you for making your code more complete. However, now it's kind of overdone: most, if not all, packages aren't needed for this problem. I suggest: a) commenting them out, compile and check what's really relevant for the rotation problem, b) delete those obsolete packages, c) update your posted code. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `\rothead` macro from the `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{makecell,rotating,tabularx,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \setlength\rotheadsize{5cm}
  \def\cellrotangle{45}
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{b{2.5cm}XXXXXXXX|}         
    Titel & 
    \rothead{C-bøjle m. hydrauliske   stempler}  & 
    \rothead{\color{red}Stor møtrik med gearet slagnøgle} &    \rothead{\color{red}Foldekrog på excentrisk aksel} & 
    \rothead{\color{red}Hydraulisk drejecylinder} & 
    \rothead{\color{red}Fremskudt ærme med indgribende hydrauliske stifter} & 
    \rothead{\color{red}Stor møtrik med hydraulik cylinder} & 
    \rothead{\color{red}Multi-møtrik m. bæltedrev}\\
    \hline 
    Konus & x & 1b & x & x & x & x & x \\
    \hline 
    Chamfer & 2a & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
    \hline 
    Stifter (fast) & 3a & 3b & x & x & x & x & x \\
    \hline 
    Stifter (fremskrubbelig) & 4a & x & x & x & x & x & x\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{Kombinationer af udarbejdet klemme- og centreringsløsninger}
  \label{tab:kombinationer}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much :)) <3

Comment: @MohammedItani You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `tabularray` package to create this table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \setlength\rotheadsize{6cm}
  \def\cellrotangle{45}
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[2.2]XXXXXXX},
    cell{1}{2-8}={valign=b,halign=c,cmd=\rotcell},
    cell{1}{3-8}={fg=red},
    hline{2-Z}={solid}
  }
    Titel & 
    C-bøjle m. hydrauliske   stempler  & 
    Stor møtrik med gearet slagnøgle &    
    Foldekrog på excentrisk aksel & 
    Hydraulisk drejecylinder & 
    Fremskudt ærme med indgribende hydrauliske stifter & 
    Stor møtrik med hydraulik cylinder & 
    Multi-møtrik m. bæltedrev\\
    Konus & x & 1b & x & x & x & x & x \\
    Chamfer & 2a & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
    Stifter (fast) & 3a & 3b & x & x & x & x & x \\
    Stifter (fremskrubbelig) & 4a & x & x & x & x & x & x\\
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{Kombinationer af udarbejdet klemme- og centreringsløsninger}
  \label{tab:kombinationer}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OMG that looks so cool! Thanks! Again:)

Comment: @MohammedItani You're welcome!